# Find the maximum value of $f = x^2+ 2y^2$ subject to constraints $y -x^2 + 1 = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, constraints

I need to find the maximum value of the $$f(x,y) = x^2 + 2y^2$$ subject to the constraint $$y-x^2+1=0$$

Now I know this problem can be solved via lagrange multipliers and I have got the maximum value as $2$.

But If i try to substitute the value of $$x^2 =y+1$$ then I get $$f = 2y^2 + y + 1$$ and clearly for this function No maximum value exist.

My question is: Why does substitution fails to give any maxima\minima for given function, also for any  similar problems which involve some constraint, Do I always need to use Lagrange multipliers only ?

Thank you.

Comment: The maximum value does not exist. Your computation using Lagrange multipliers is likely incorrect.

Comment: @NoChance  You must use Lagrange multiplier method. substitution does not work.

Comment: @Nochance $x^2 = y+1$,$f =2y^2+ y+1$,my substitution is correct

Comment: By substituion $x=0$, $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$  will be extermum, but non of them are maxima. $$f(x=0)=1$$ and $$f(x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})=\frac78$$

Comment: You forgot that there’s an extremum at the boundary of $x^2=y+1$, namely at $y=-1$.